# How to receive HTTP cookies from a web server in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

How to receive HTTP cookies from a web server in PHP?

Comment: Well, and then send them back to the server... I want to login in this way.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to recieve cookies from a remote webserver using PHP? Or are you simply refering to viewing cookies sent from a client browser?

Comment: 0 
 
 
 
How would I go about writing a simple PHP bot that could login in and recieve all the cookies sent by the server? ... and then send them back when required?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In that case, ignore the answers about $_COOKIE and setcookie, what you need is an HTTP client library, such as Zend_Http or HTTPRequest extension.

Comment: Yep, I'm googling for those. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to interact with cookies from a remote webserver using PHP, rather than simply manipulating cookies from a client browser.

In that case, take a look at the [Zend_Http](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) and related classes in the Zend Framework. These let you perform HTTP requests with cookie persistence and a whole lot more besides.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [HTTPRequest](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) class and take a look at the [getCookies](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-getcookies.php) and [setCookies](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-setcookies.php) functions. You can also use the $_COOKIES but it's much more low level.

Comment: **@the_drow:** The PECL HTTP Extension is not bundled with PHP.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the $_[COOKIES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) superglobal

> Well, and then send them back to the server... I want to login in this way

This suggests you want to know how to send them to the browser in the browser place.

See [setcookie](https://www.php.net/setcookie).

Comment: Next time try to elaborate more. If he doesn't know the $_COOKIES superglobal then he's new to php.

Comment: A fast answer to a fast question seems fair to me.

Comment: That's why I made $_COOKIES ... a link!