# Run cronjob as a logged in user

Tags: php, cron

I am currently running a php cronjob to crawl through some HTML. I have come to a scenario where I have to be logged in to access some data. How can this be achieved?

The cronjob is running on a server which I dont have access to.

Basically, let's just say, I am trying to access some HTML data which is only available after a user logs in. I have the login details but dont know how to implement it with the cronjob.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

By "user logs in", I suppose you mean "user would log in if he was using a browser" ?

If yes, your PHP script that's crawling through HTML will need to :

- POST data like if it was filling in the form
- Get the answer from the server ; probably extract the session's cookies
- Send those cookies for subsequent requests

You might be interested in using some already-existing library to facilitate that.

For instance, you can take a look at [`Zend_Http_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html#zend.http.client.usage) ([see also](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html) ; the part about [Sending Multiple Requests With the Same Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html#zend.http.client.multiple_requests) will probably interest you ;-) )

You might also want to take a look at some other questions/answers, like :

- [How would I go about writing a simple PHP bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217434/how-would-i-go-about-writing-a-simple-php-bot)
- [How to receive HTTP cookies from a web server in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217382/how-to-receive-http-cookies-from-a-web-server-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleBrowser](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html) from SimpleTest for automating crawling. It's part of the SimpleTest framework, but it can be used on its own.