# How to programmatically log in into phpBB forum?

Tags: php, mysql, integration, phpbb

I have a forum using phpBB. Now i would like to do something like this from source code:

login("user", "password")

How to do this in phpBB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need a script that integrates with the phpBB framework. Something like this should work.

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
?>
```

Then, look at the [$auth->login()](http://area51.phpbb.com/docs/code/30x/phpbb3/auth.html#login%28%29) function (an example use is in the `login_box()` function in `/includes/functions.php`). A simplistic yet incomplete example is:

```
$result = $auth->login($username, $password); // There are more params but they're optional

if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
{
    // Logged in
}
else
{
    // Something went wrong
}
```

Answer (score 11):

First you need to bootstrap for phpBB:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './phpBB/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

$user->session_begin();
```

You'll have to replace the `./phpBB/` part with the relative path to the forum.

To make the user logged in, you have to do:

```
$result = $user->session_create($user_id, $admin, $autologin, $viewonline);
```

`$admin` should probably be `false`, `$autologin` and `$viewonline` depend on what you want.

**NOTE:** Calling `session_create` will set the session cookie for the user, so make sure you only call that when the current request is actually serving that user.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, as your solution is not accepting the user's username/password to log them in, but forcing a login of a specfic `$user_id`.

Comment: Fair enough, I did go a bit too far into the details. I'll leave my answer here anyway, since I put some effort into it. Might help someone someday.

Comment: I know that's quite late, but thanks a lot for taking the decision to leave the answer, because that's the only place I've found a solution to how to login users using only the user ID and not the password.

Comment: For people looking for a way to change the logged in user, you can do this in a similar manner. `$user->session_kill(); $user->session_create($newUserID, false, true); $auth->acl($user->data);` I'm using this to switch to an anonymous user (userid=1) before my script does some automatic posting, then switching back to the original user (whos userid I have stored before making the switch).

Answer (score -1):

In your PHP script that's crawling through HTML will need to :

- POST data like if it was filling in the form
- Get the answer from the server ; probably extract the session's cookies
- Send those cookies for subsequent requests

You might be interested in using some already-existing library to facilitate that.

For instance, you can take a look at [`Zend_Http_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html#zend.http.client.usage) ([see also](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html) ; the part about [Sending Multiple Requests With the Same Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html#zend.http.client.multiple_requests) will probably interest you ;-) )

You might also want to take a look at some other questions/answers, like :

- [How would I go about writing a simple PHP bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217434/how-would-i-go-about-writing-a-simple-php-bot)
- [How to receive HTTP cookies from a web server in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217382/how-to-receive-http-cookies-from-a-web-server-in-php)

Comment: Not really sure how this has to do with phpBB?

Comment: The question was: "How to programmatically log in into phpBB forum?". This is a good general answer explaining that.

Comment: @budwiser - The question was how to login to **phpBB**, not how to generally log into any remote web application. So, it's not well-suited for phpBB, especially when there's an API available and this answer is talking about crawling HTML and remote authentication. (The OP's question clearly states the need for a local authentication solution)